# Copy multiple Tds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 3 columns and 6 rows. I want to copy the contents of some of them into a newly created column, but insert them in the middle. So that it looks like that:

[image]

With this aprroach:

```
$("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=2]").each(function(i) {
  var $newCell = $(this).wrap('<td></td').parent();
  var $newRow = $("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=1]").eq(i).parents('tr');
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  $newRow.append($newCell);
});

$("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=3]").each(function(i) {
  var $newCell = $(this).wrap('<td></td').parent();
  var $newRow = $("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=1]").eq(i).parents('tr');
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  $newRow.append($newCell);
});
```

I get that result:

[image]

So the new columns should be inserted between the very left column and the column with `Abc` and not at the very right.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vyyyfqd8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert something in the middle of the table what you can do is use either [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/). For example, we want to insert our new cell before the `Abc` item so instead of inserting it on the end you can use the below code to insert it before `Abc` (*being the last `td`*):

```
// Find the last element, and add the new cell before it.
$newRow.find("td:last").before($newCell);
```

[**Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/vyyyfqd8/1/)

---

If you would like to be more specific, you can specify the element by it's text in the selector. So in this case you can state before a `td` element containing the text `'Abc'`:

```
$newRow.find("td:contains('Abc')").before($newCell);
```